# Looking for atmospheric dispersion model with 3d GIS application

Tags: arcgis-desktop, open-source-gis, free-software

is there any [atmospheric dispersion model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_dispersion_modeling) with 3d GIS application that can use DEM and atmospheric data as input ?

Comment: Possibly related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40472/how-can-i-create-a-pollutant-dispersion-raster-in-qgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what looks to be one described in a PDF entitled [DUSTRAN 1.0 User’s Guide:
A GIS-Based Atmospheric Dust Dispersion Modeling System](http://www.pnl.gov/main/publications/external/technical_reports/pnnl-16055.pdf):

> The U.S. Department of Energy’s Pacific Northwest National Laboratory
>   just completed a multi-year project to develop a fully tested and
>   documented atmospheric dispersion modeling system (DUST TRANsport or
>   DUSTRAN) to assist the U.S. Department of Defense (DoD) in addressing
>   particulate air quality issues at military training and testing
>   ranges. The project was primarily funded by DoD’s Strategic
>   Environmental Research and Development Program with additional funding
>   from the U.S. Forest Service and U.S. Environmental Protection Agency
>   (EPA) to address their issues related to the “off-target” drift of
>   aerially applied pesticides.

Although, 3D is not mentioned in that paper, it seems to be based on ArcMap so presumably the results could be displayed in ArcScene or ArcGlobe.

Answer (score 2):

I was using ISC for similar case but only for points as sources. But I know it handles also lines and volumes. More info about models including ISC is here:

http://www.epa.gov/scram001/dispersion_alt.htm