# How to find a single point furthest from any road?

Tags: qgis

I have a road layer of a country. What method or plugin would you suggest, to **find a single point furthest from any road**

(but as you can see, there is a coastline, so points in the sea can't count)

The road layer looks like this:

[image: road layer]

Comment: Your question isn't well specified. A large area could be a convex polygon (perhaps much longer than "wide") paralleling a road, but no point in the polygon may be very far from a road. What are you trying to show? What have you already looked at?

Comment: I am looking for two things: area by size that is surrounded by roads, and also a single point that is furthest from any roads.

Comment: That sounds like two questions so I recommend that you edit this one to focus on whichever of the two things is important to have answered first. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: sorry about that. 

in that case: single point furthest from any road (but as you can see, there is a coastline, so points in the sea can't count)

Comment: The question is for points, but the approach is the same: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis

Comment: Check if you can generate a Voronoï diagram of your road network: The location you are looking for is a node of the Voronoï graph.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn could you post your comment as an answer so this thread no longer shows up on the unanswered list? Thanks!

Comment: @underdark Ok, done. I didn't want to plagiarize. Credits should go to Maxim Dubinin who answered the other question. Not sure how to deal with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to rasterize the layer and then you can use proximity analysis from the GDAL Tools plugin: Raster > Analysis > Proximity.

More information can be found in the following related answer: [Calculating distance to points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/21576/9839)

Comment: Thanks so much! Here is the result :) 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m705f0kne4mpwci/Screenshot%202014-04-30%2011.46.43.jpg