# Distance buffer from point, with obstacles

Tags: qgis, buffer

In QGIS is there a tool or technique that would draw a fixed distance buffer from a point, taking into account obstacles in the buffer field?

I want to illustrate the maximum distance a ship can travel from a port in a given time, including going around headlands and islands.

Comment: So basically you want to do a travel time analysis for ships. Have you tried doing some research?

Comment: Yes! but the plugins I can find / understand seem to be all focused on travel time analysis along specific networks (roads, public transport etc). Am I missing something?

Comment: I would use raster cost distance. This video shows a much more detailed analysis than you would be performing but it should help. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmkmBTkzF8I

Comment: may be ? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189847/cost-distance-map-in-qgis