# Making land-use raster reclassification in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, land-classification, landscape

I have been struggling with the task of creating a least-cost path between two points on a land-use map.
So far I have got the raster as follows (category names don't matter right now)

[image]

So these 7 categories are the values of my raster cells, right? (0-6). I would like to change these for:
0 to 100 (highest cost)
1 to 0 (lowest cost)
2 to 80 (high cost)
3 to 30 
And so on... (the logic behind this would be of an animal crossing it, that's why it looks odd).

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to reclassify this. I see people talking about this with DEM files, but I haven't found much information about how can I do this with a "simple" land-use raster. Am I trying to work with too little information?
I believe once I get this reclassified, it will be easy to calculate the least-cost path between two points in the raster, right?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121532/how-to-reclass-a-raster-with-reclassify-grid-values-in-qgis

Comment: You can also do this with the raster calculator, see http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator and there is an example there

Comment: Calculating cost-distance: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140560/cost-distance-analyst-in-qgis?rq=1