# QGIS equivalent to ArcGIS "corridor" tool for Least Cost Path analysis

Tags: qgis, dem, least-cost

I am working on solving a task in QGIS that is supposed to be solved in ArcGIS Pro (the examples given here are modified to not show the actual solution of the official task). Cost surfaces given as a DEM transformed to slope values have to be analysed with given start and end point of a hiking trail. I used the "Least Cost Path" distance analysis tool to find the path, see screenshot (red: LCP based on slope values, pink: LCP based on 4 slope cost categories to get a more realistic hiking trail).

[image: Two LCPs based on slope and slope cost categories]

In the next step, a least cost corridor has to be analysed that contains all routes that are maximum 3% more expensive than the "cheapest" solution. In ArcGIS Pro, there is a "corridor" tool (see [Cost Distance Analyst In QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140560)).

What is the QGIS equivalent for this tool?