# How to obtain an euclidean distance raster from a vector file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, distance

I'm trying to obtain a raster of Euclidean Distances from a vector layer I have of a river in Spain. I did it very easily with ArcMap using Euclidean Distance, but I don't know how to do it in QGIS.[image: this is the river polygon shapefile]

I just want to obtain a raster with all the distances from the river so I can then reclassify it, so it would look like this one I already created with ArcMap. [image: euclidean distance from ArcMap, already reclassified]

Comment: there's an answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis

Comment: I get this message when trying to convert to raster: "The output file doesn't exist. You must set up the output size or resolution to create it." I'm not sure what does it means to select an output file.

Comment: can you take a screen grab of the dialogue box before you run the tool?

Comment: You ask how to obtain a raster of euclidean distances to classify in the next step. Consider to simply create a multi distance buffer. There are 2 plugins available to accomplish that task.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but I figured it out! I wasn't specifying the pixel resolution and that's why the error message appeared. By the way, I didn't thought about the multi distance buffer, sounds reasonable. thanks!