# Creating raster displaying graduated Distance to polygon or feature using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, distance, rasterization

I am trying to create a raster which displays the relative distance of a pixel to a set of polygons of a specific value.

I have satellite derived fire scar data going back for the last 20 years.

For the purposes of my analysis any vegetation older that 3 years is classified as long un-burnt (this analysis is for a particularly fire prone region). The rest is classed as young vegetation.

It is easy enough to produce a shp/raster which, displays these two classes either in separate files or together. My first thought was to convert the files to geotif and do a proximity analysis in QGIS, I then tried a multi distance buffer but this didn't work properly either.

The blue polygons are old vegetation, the pink are younger. Ideally the raster will display a graduation scale of distance from the blue polygons (including the blue polygons which would display 0m/km).

[image]

Comment: Euclidean Distance https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis sounds like what you're after.

Comment: Try displaying the blue polygon layer with an [inverted polygon renderer style](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#inverted-polygon-renderer) and a shapeburst fill style.