# Obtain distance of each raster pixels from anoth feature/ proximity tool failing

Tags: qgis, raster, distance

I have a raster with population densities for Vietnam. Each pixel contains 1 population count. For the purpose of my analysis, I'd like to find the distance of each of the pixels to a line feature, representing the coastline as shown in the picture.
[image]

I have read a similar question in an other thread: [Calculating distance to points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis) and managed to rasterize my coastline (even though there is a big gap in the southern part of the coastline).

[image]

When I try to use the proximity tool I get the following message on the log: *The following layers were not correctly generated*. I tried to save in different areas my output map but the error message keeps on coming back.
What I need is just the distance of each pixel from that coastline, similarly to what the "distance to nearest hub" tool does with vector data.