# Rasterizing vector creates raster with all cells containing same value but different color using QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, rasterization

I have a vector layer which i am trying to rasterize. It is smaller than the study area.  The end goal is to create a layer with euclidean distance from said rasterized vector layer.

When rasterizing, I use another raster layer covering the whole study area for the output extent. I think this should give me the value 1 for "presence" of my vector and 0 for "absence" in the respective locations. However, I get the value 1 for all cells in my raster layer but the color is differentiated according to the vector i rasterized. The black pixels form the correct shape but the surrounding transparent pixels have the same value.

How do I get this raster with the transparent pixels set to 0?

I followed the answer to this question: [Calculating distance to points in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21575/calculating-distance-to-points-in-qgis) and added a new column to my attribute table which i populated with 1 before rasterizing. I used this field as my "field to use for burn-in value". I believe this might be where my mistake stems from but if I leave that field empty i get a completely empty raster layer with values that don't make sense (see layer "Rasterized" in screenshot).

I also tried to set the accuracy in the layer styling panel to actual but to no avail.

[image: study area with raster layer over top, only the raster layer with the values 1 and 1 for black and transparent acutally appears, black is shape of rasterized vector layer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delete the fixed value for burn-in and use a value from a field. Then you'll get different raster values for different polygons. Use ID or some other field that you have in your polygons, eg 1 for land, 2 for water, etc.